# how get image cache from isolatestorage with js in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

i can download some images from  network with C# code ,then store in isolatedstorage ,but i can't get image cache from isolatedstorage  with js code; phonegap return base64 to html client  ,i don't think this way is perfect;
  the way:"ms-appdata:///..." is not ok.